# How to check elements in list "are" numbers in Python?

Tags: python, string

Here is simple code:

```
s = ['-1', '2', '+']
print([x.isnumeric() for x in s])
print([x.isdigit() for x in s])
```

The output is

```
[False, True, False]
[False, True, False]
```

What I wish is:

```
[True, True, False]
```

Comment: Maybe instead use a function which attempts a conversion to `int` and catches any exceptions, returning False in case of exception and True otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a not a one liner but this works.

```
def isnum(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

s = ['-1', '2', '+']
print([isnum(x) for x in s])
```

Comment: I'd use `float` instead of `int`; it'll return true for any value Python recognizes as a number (int, float, scientific notation) instead of only integers.

Comment: _"Its a not a one liner but this works"_ - I'd take clear readable code over a one-liner any day.

Answer (score 1):

```
[x.isnumeric() or (x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isnumeric()) for x in s]
```

Comment: What about numbers such as `+1` or `+2`?

Comment: guess you could do. `x[0] in ('-', '+')` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regular expression pattern to match negative, positive, and decimal numbers:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['-1', '2', '+']
>>> [re.match('^(-|\+)?\d+(.\d+)?', n) is not None for n in s]
[True, True, False]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop, and a replace you can easily check whether values in list are digits or not.

Example:

```
list = ['-1','2','+']
result=[]
for i in list:
        if '-' in i:
                result.append(i.replace('-','').isdigit())
        else:
                result.append(i.isdigit())
```

output:

```
>>> list = ['-1','2','+']
>>> result=[]
>>> for i in list:
...         if '-' in i:
...                 result.append(i.replace('-','').isdigit())
...         else:
...                 result.append(i.isdigit())
... 
>>> print result
[True, True, False]
```

For cases where the number is a float or decimal, you can easily add more if statements.